# What does Natural Order mean In this context in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a question which appeared in a past paper (I'm revising for my exams) and I came across this word natural order which appears to be a keywords since it was written in bold on the paper. I've looked online at Natural Order but I couldn't find anything that related it to arraylist's like my question asks.

*Please note, I do not need help solving the actual question, I just wish to understand what natural order means.*

**Question:**

> Write a Java static method called atLeast which takes an ArrayList of objects which
>   have natural order, an object of the element type of the ArrayList, and an integer n. A
>   call to the method should return true if at least n elements of the ArrayList are greater
>   than the element type object according to natural order, otherwise it should return false.

Comment: What is the class of objects this `List` contains?

Comment: Natural order is one judging by which, taking any 2 objects of same type, you can say, which object is bigger by value and which is smaller, or they are equal. In Java, if class `T` implements `Comparable<T>`, it is called having natural order.

Comment: So if I have an `ArrayList` of `Person` objects, what would be their natural ordering? Their age? Their height? Their weight? I think the question is missing crucial information. The `ArrayList` is most likely limited to java types that implement `Comparable` such as Integer, String, etc. You should add this as an assumption when you answer such a question or tell the invigilator that the question is ambiguous.

Comment: @ChetanKinger The purpose of a natural order is that we don't have to know what it actually is, just that it exists by way of Comparable. So we don't actually need that information to write the method or answer the question.

Comment: @Radiodef That's exactly what I said. I just added that such an assumption should be mentioned while answering the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This likely means the objects in the List implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's *natural ordering*, and the class's `compareTo` method is referred to as its *natural comparison* method.

The declaration would look something like this:

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
boolean atLeast(List<T> list, T key, int n) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Right, so it make sense as I used the compareTo method to answer the question. Are there any other types of ordering relating to comparable or comparator?

Comment: @Aceboy1993 That seems to be the case, yes, you are supposed to use `compareTo`. *natural order* is the ordering imposed by `Comparable`, we can use a `Comparator` to impose some other ordering besides the natural order.

Answer (score 1):

Natural order means the default ordering for a particular type of collection. It actually depends upon the type of collection you are using. eg. if its a string collection, it will be sorted in alphabetical order, for numbers it follows numerical order.

Refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) for better understanding about natural ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/sorting.html) for detail.
For objects to have a natural order they must implement the interface `java.lang.Comparable.` In other words, the objects must be comparable to determine their order. Here is how the Comparable interface looks:

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
  int compareTo(T o);
}
```